# Is every Borel set a countable union of intervals?

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, borel-sets

Since the Borel $\sigma$ algebra is generated by all open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and all open sets are the countable union of disjoint open intervals, I figured that any Borel set is the countable union of intervals. I also used the fact that if we only use '$\sigma $ algebra operations' on intervals then we get an interval or countable union of intervals.
But I ask if this is actually true?

Comment: $\mathbb Q$ is a Borel set. In $\sigma$-algebras you can do countable unions and complements, therefore you can do countable intersections, and so any single-point set is a Borel set. Then, $\mathbb Q$ as a countable union of single-point sets is a Borel set and so on.

Comment: @StinkingBishop That would still be ok if one allows one-point closed intervals. However, $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ is also Borel ans is not the countable union of connected sets

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Agreed, I was thinking OP was only considering countable unions of *open* intervals ... Indeed they may need a bit more involved counterexample.

Answer (score 7):

The Cantor set $C$ is an uncountable Borel set and it does not contain any non-trivial interval (i.e. a singleton).

Hence $C$ can not be written an as countable union of intervals.

However, its complement is indeed a countable union of disjoint open intervals!

Answer (score 1):

The sets you are talking about are special cases of what are called $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^0_3$ sets using the [Borel hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy) notation.

To explain, we start with intervals. Every interval can be written as an intersection of countably many open intervals. Sets obtained this way are also called $G_\delta$ sets, and denoted by $\boldsymbol{\Pi}^0_2$ in the Borel hierarchy. So every interval is a $\boldsymbol{\Pi}^0_2$ set. That means that a set that is a union of countably many intervals is, in particular, a union of countably many $\boldsymbol{\Pi}^0_2$ sets. Such sets are denoted by $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^0_3$ sets. However, the Borel hierarchy does not stop here, but rather continues up through $\boldsymbol{\Pi}^0_\alpha$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^0_\alpha$ sets for all countable ordinals $\alpha$. Moreover, it can be shown that every level of this hierarchy is proper. So in conclusion there are Borel sets that are *much* more complicated than unions of countably many intervals.

Comment: Any interval is also a union of countably many closed intervals and thus an $F_\sigma$ (also called $\Sigma_2$) set. This means that a union of intervals is actually $\Sigma_2$.